# Count ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, csv, observablecollection

I have the below observevale collection which works perfectly:

```
        Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            var column = line.Split(',');
            var name = column[0];
            int score = int.Parse(column[1].ToString());
            var person = Persons.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);

            if (person == null)
            {
                var newPerson = new Person(name, score);
                Persons.Add(newPerson);
            }

            else
            {
                person.Score += score;
            }

            datagrid.ItemsSource = Persons;
        }
```

What I am doing here is that I am first reading from a CSV file which has two columns, name and score. And what I want to do is go through the CSV file and get the sum of the score of the names that are similar.

so for example, my CSV is like the below table:

```
   Name, score
   Jo,1
   Hannah,2
   Sara,1
   Jo,2
   Sara,3
   Fred,1
```

When I run my code, I get the below result which is exactly what I want:

```
    Jo,3
    Hannah,2
    Sara,4
    Fred,1
```

The other thing I am trying to do is to count how many "Jo" we have, how many "Hannah" we have, how many "Sara" we have and how many "Fred" we have. And I know since the names are stored in the ObservableCollection, Persons, so I want to count how many elements are in the ObservableCollection given that the I only count the names that are the same. So to do this, I used the count property for the ObservableCollection. So I did this:

```
   Persons.Count;
```

But this keeps returning 1. I thought maybe I need to place it outside of the loop, but I am getting the same thing.

My question is, why is the count behaving this way? Am I using it wrong? Shouldn't Count count all the elements in the ObservableCollection?

Comment: ObservableCollection returns count of elements that it has.Where do you get element count from `Persons`? Can you put it to question's code?

Comment: You're showing what works, that's cool. Can we see the code you have issues with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the count behaving this way?

Count is suppose to return the number of items in the collection.

> Am I using it wrong?

Based on your expectations, yes.

> Shouldn't Count count all the elements in the ObservableCollection?

Yes it does. You are adding the grouped items to the collection so there would only be one of each name.

Using linq for demonstration purposes.

Assuming `lines` holds

```
Name, score
Jo,1
Hannah,2
Sara,1
Jo,2
Sara,3
Fred,1
```

The following returns anonymous object that hold the parsed data

```
var data = lines.Skip(1).Select(line => {
    var column = line.Split(',');
    var name = column[0];
    int score = int.Parse(column[1]);
    return new { name, score };
});
```

Grouping that data would provide the ability to aggregate the scores and how many of each name exists

```
var groupedData = data.GroupBy(p => p.name)
    .Select(g => new { name = g.Key, score = g.Sum(p => p.score), count = g.Count() });

//eg
//Jo,3,2
//Hannah,2,1
//Sara,4,2
//Fred,1,1
```

From there you should be able to create your desired objects including how many of each name exists.

```
 var persons = groupedData.Select(p => new Person(p.name, p.score) { Count = p.count });
```

persons can now be added to collection.

```
foreach (var person in persons) {
    Persons.Add(person);
}
datagrid.ItemsSource = Persons;
```

Answer (score 1):

To get count of persons in your CSV file you can use `Count()`:

```
var personName = "Jo";

var count = lines.Count(l => l.Split(',')[0] == personName);
```

Now you have count of `"Jo"` in your file;